# Disable Relying Party Discovery

Tags: dotnetopenauth

Is it possible to disable Relying Party Discovery on DotNetOpenAuth using some configuration value, or would I need to do it by modifying code? If configuration value, what would it be, if code, what file should I be looking at?

Problem with RP Discovery is that RP in question doesn't support it and it is causing 10 sec delay in authentication when DotNetOpenAuth is trying to query RP until the HTTP GET times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that this wasn't configurable in DotNetOpenAuth, but was in fact done (in the sample code) on the Decide.aspx page, so it was possible comment out the lines.

```
relyingPartyVerificationResultLabel.Text =
ProviderEndpoint.PendingRequest.IsReturnUrlDiscoverable(ProviderEndpoint.Provider.Channel.WebRequestHandler) == RelyingPartyDiscoveryResult.Success ? "passed" : "failed";

realmLabel.Text = ProviderEndpoint.PendingRequest.Realm.ToString();
```

Comment: Correct, but you can't control what other Providers may perform RP discovery, so it's a good idea to support it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, it is not possible to disable discovery, correct?  Just want to confirm the above.

Comment: It is possible, by commenting out the lines as mentioned above, but not recommended UNLESS you know none of the RPs require that. In our case it was a "closed" system so we wanted to get rid of it due to the  10 sec delay that was caused when RP didn't support Discovery.